# Source of Ramayana Mantra

Tags: rama, identification-request, shloka

Please let me know the source of shloka

> राघवो विजयं दद्यात् मम सीतापतिः प्रभुः ।
>   राघवस्य यथत्द्वन्द्वं दद्यात् वैभवम् ॥
>
> raaghavo vijayam dadyAt mama sItApatiH prabhuH|
>   raaghavasya yathatdvandvam dadyAt amita vaibhavam||
>
> Meaning:
>   May   Raaghavan,   the   Lord   of   SeethA   PirAtti   grant   me   victory   in   my  kaimkaryams!  May  His  sacred  pair  of  feet  bless  me  with  limitless  glory  of  Kaimkaryam to Him !

I want to know from where this mantra has been picked

Comment: I found this is [related to Sundara Kanda of Ramayana](https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Sundara%20Kandam.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

This shloka was given by Ramanuja Acharya as a mantra for Sundarakanda. I am not sure about the Hindi letters but in Telugu, letters are allotted certain number. So when you take the first sentence राघवो विजयं दद्यात् मम सीतापतिः प्रभुः । or in Telugu when each letter is given the value

రా ఘ వో వి జ యo ద ధ్వాన్ మ మ సీ తా ప తి: ప్ర భు: = no of letters = 16 (16 days)
2   4  4  4 8  1   8   1    5  5  7  6  1 6   2  4    = 68(68 Sargas in Sundara Kanda)

So best way of doing Sundarakanda Parayana is for 16 days and each day you should read the no of Sargas as the numbers allocated for the mantra.
example: first day 2 Sargas, second day 4, third day 4......so on..

This information was provided by Nanduri Srinivas in one of his Youtube videos about Sundarakand